# Deleting points based on number of neighbours using ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, proximity

I have one point dataset of around 270,000 points. I have another larger point dataset of about 3.5 million points.

I would like to make a 5 km radius around each 270,000 points of the first dataset. If this radius contains less than 3 points (both point datasets together), I would like to delete all points within this radius using ArcGIS.

How can I do this?

Comment: You need to start with Near, but I'd argue against using Delete when it's so much faster to select the features to keep and save them to a new feature class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a better solution, but here is one idea:

- Merge the datasets
- Create a field on the attribute of merge result, populate this field
  with the number 1.
- Point to Raster using this field as value
- Focal Statistics - Circle with radius of 5 km, statistics type: Sum
- Reclassify the new raster: 3 to max value = 1, 0-2 = NoData
- Raster to Point

You will probably have to use a spatial join to recover the attributes of the points if you want. If you need to separate the datasets again you will need to have a field in common from both datasets and populate it accordingly to each dataset, then in the end you can use select by attributes and then export it.

I'm sure that someone will have a solution with less steps, but this is one idea that I think will work.